# Avoiding double scrollbars with Grid Component and a website header

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm trying to add a website header to my site that uses the `<Grid>` component.  How do I nest the website header to avoid getting the browser scrollbar and the `<Grid>` scrollbar?

I want to push the Grid down to allow for the website header while allowing the Window / Browser to control the scroll for both.

I'm using these components 
`<WindowScroller><AutoSizer><Grid>`

[image]

I see on https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/ the WindowScroller it works properly (using the `VirtualScroll` component).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you're specifying the `autoHeight` property on the inner `Grid`. This property tells it to overflow rather than scroll.

So you want something like this:

```
<WindowScroller>
  {({ height, isScrolling, scrollTop }) => (
    <AutoSizer disableHeight>
      {({ width }) => (
        <Grid
          autoHeight
          height={height}
          rowRenderer={({ index }) => this._rowRenderer({ index, isScrolling })}
          scrollTop={scrollTop}
          width={width}
          {..otherProps}
        />
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
  )}
</WindowScroller>
```

Comment: Perfect - I was missing the scrollTop param as well in my test. It doesn't seem to work without that which makes sense.

Comment: Fantastic. :) Happy to hear!